# BayesianOptimization search errors out "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable"

Tags: python-3.x, neural-network

I am getting the error

> TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

from the following line:

```
tuner_nn.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(x_val,y_val ), verbose=0, callbacks=[Earlystopping])
```

I know there are a lot of questions with the the same error but still could not find a solution for this issue.

While removing the **y_val** from the code and having the following incomplete line:

(Why the removal of y_val the code works? Moreover, there is no error for missing argument)

```
tuner_nn.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(x_val,), verbose=0, callbacks=[Earlystopping])
```

The code somewhy pass without errors with green V.

Yet with the warnings:

> INFO:tensorflow:Oracle triggered exit
> INFO:tensorflow:Reloading Oracle from existing project /Users/Farid Srouji/Documents/kerastuner\untitled_project\oracle.json
> INFO:tensorflow:Reloading Tuner from /Users/Farid Srouji/Documents/kerastuner\untitled_project\tuner0.json
> INFO:tensorflow:Oracle triggered exit
> INFO:tensorflow:Reloading Oracle from existing project /Users/Farid Srouji/Documents/kerastuner\untitled_project\oracle.json
> INFO:tensorflow:Reloading Tuner from /Users/Farid Srouji/Documents/kerastuner\untitled_project\tuner0.json
> INFO:tensorflow:Oracle triggered exit

The full code in this block is:

```
# Search hyperparameters

SEED = 121

# NN

tuner_nn = BayesianOptimization(nn_builder,
objective = 'val_loss',
max_trials = 20,
seed = SEED,
directory = '/Users/myuser/Documents/kerastuner',
overwrite = True
)

tuner_nn.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(x_val, ), verbose=0, callbacks=[Earlystopping])

## Build model based on the optimized hyperparameters

besthp_nn = tuner_nn.get_best_hyperparameters()[0]
model_nn = tuner_nn.hypermodel.build(besthp_nn)

# lstm

tuner_lstm = BayesianOptimization(lstm_builder,
objective = 'val_loss',
max_trials = 20,
seed = SEED,
directory = '/Users/myuser/Documents/kerastuner')

tuner_lstm.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), verbose=0, callbacks=[Earlystopping])

## Build model based on the optimized hyperparameters

besthp_lstm = tuner_lstm.get_best_hyperparameters()[0]
model_lstm = tuner_lstm.hypermodel.build(besthp_lstm)

# gru

tuner_gru = BayesianOptimization(gru_builder,
objective = 'val_loss',
max_trials = 20,
seed = SEED,
directory = '/Users/myuser/Documents/kerastuner')

tuner_gru.search(x_train, y_train, epochs=50, validation_data=(x_val, y_val), verbose=0, callbacks=[Earlystopping])

## Build model based on the optimized hyperparameters

besthp_gru = tuner_gru.get_best_hyperparameters()[0]
model_gru = tuner_gru.hypermodel.build(besthp_gru)
```

The shapes are:

```
x_val.shape
>> (77, 1, 4)
y_val.shape
>> (77, 1)
```

And the input looks like:
x_val

```
array([[[-8.18383474e-01,  9.87717268e-01, -4.80814592e-02,
         -2.13148572e-02]],

...

       [[ 5.40588227e-02,  1.39460804e+00, -7.51897863e-01,
         -1.08002924e+00]]])
```

y_val

```
array([[18.18],
       [15.49],
...
       [17.33],
       [19.61]])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the proble comes from the following lines

```
besthp_nn = tuner_nn.get_best_hyperparameters()\[0\]
```

and

```
besthp_gru = tuner_gru.get_best_hyperparameters()\[0\]
```

You might want to try something like

```
besthp_nn = tuner_nn.get_best_hyperparameters(1)[0]
besthp_gru = tuner_gru.get_best_hyperparameters(1)[0]
```

Comment: The error appears in a line before reaching the lines you indicated

Comment: May be change and the ```callbacks= \[Earlystopping\] ```to ```callbacks=[Earlystopping]```.

Comment: They are already callbacks=[Earlystopping].
Only the display here at stackoverflow shows it with "\"

Answer (score 0):

Python raises the TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable if you use indexing or slicing with the square bracket notation on a float variable that is not indexable.

Comment: What could be the solution?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).